# How Can I Switch Settings.settings between DEBUG and RELEASE mode?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a url, to be more specific, a web service url, in Project/Properties/Settings.settings. It is added by Visual Studio when I add a web service reference.

The url should be different between DEBUG and RELEASE mode, how can I set up Visual Studio so that it build with correct url under DEBUG/RELEASE?

PS: I don't want to modify Settings.settings manually because it is not suggested by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

The auto generated proxy class inherited from SoapHttpClientProtocol has a property "Url", which you can set to point web service to another location. So I can save the web service link in config file, and fetch it to "Url" on the newly created proxy client object:

```
string serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
QisWebServiceClient qis = new QisWebServiceClient();
qis.Url = serviceUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have both urls in your Settings file. And then you can access the specific settings depending on the current mode:

```
#if DEBUG
    string myUrl = Properties.Settings.Default.DebugUrl;
#else
    string myUrl = Properties.Settings.Default.ReleaseUrl;
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, this piece of code is auto-generated by Visual Studio, too. I'm doing: right click on my project - add service reference - advanced - add web reference.

Comment: In most cases, I create separate Projects for the 'Service Client Layer'. Then you don't have to deal with this problem anymore. You can always use your application settings, the auto-generated values will not be used at runtime anymore.